# вывести числа и количество их повторений в массиве

Tags: java

при выводе не должно быть дубликатов.Например,вводим 1 1 1 1 4 4 4 5 5 5
должно вывести 1 4; 4 3; 5 3; java

Comment: числа уже отсортированы?

Comment: нет,они могут быть в разброс

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться Stream Api.

1. Пусть `arr` -> массив int, например: `int[] arr = {1 1 1 1 4 4 4 5 5 5}`
2. Получить `IntStream` из массива: [`Arrays.stream(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-)
3. Вызвать у полученного `IntStream` метод [`boxed`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--), чтобы получить `Stream<Integer>`
4. У полученного Stream вызвать метод [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-)
5. Передать в данный метод коллектор [grouppingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-)
6. Коллектору в качестве параметров передать функцию одинаковости, в данном случае можно использовать [Function.identity](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#identity--), для того, чтобы знать *что* группировать, и вторым параметром коллектор [`counting`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#counting--), чтобы указать *как* группировать
7. Получить результат `Map<Integer, Long>`, в котором ключом будет элемент из массива, а значением - количество таких элементов в массиве.
8. Вывести результат с помощью [System.out.println](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#out)

Comment: напишите пожалуйста код

Comment: просто я новичок,только начинаю изучать java и готовыми классами пользоваться не могу